# bootstrap 3 ipad issue

Tags: html, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm currently going through my site testing it at present mobile / desktop is fine, the issue I have is with ipad when viewing the search page on an ipad the tiles are squashed up against the left i.e 1 pic per row, ideally I would like to see two if not three in a row but I cannot get it to work as expected, the HTML mark up for the page is as follows:

```
<section class="catalog-grid">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="filters-mobile col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-5">
                <div class="shop-filters" style="display: block;">
                    <form action="/search/members" method="post">
                        <div class="widget">
                            <h5 class="widget-title font-alt">Filter</h5>
                        </div>
                        Filter stuff goes here
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
            @*THIS IS WHERE THE RESULTS / PROFILES ARE RENDERED*@
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-9">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="tile">
                            <div class="badges">
                            </div>
                            <a href='/member/1/new-to-melbourne'>
                                <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/q_100,c_fill,h_255,w_255,g_face/mhcoeigrttdgemwjuig7" alt="Atkinson1988" />
                            </a>
                            <div class="footer">
                                <a href='/member/1/new-to-melbourne'>Atkinson1988</a>
                                <span> - <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i> Victoria, St kilda road<br /></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="tile">
                            <div class="badges">
                            </div>
                            <a href='/member/4/female-2-asian-male-tp'>
                                <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/q_100,c_fill,h_255,w_255,g_face/t4leodsoxa0h5zaqomt7" alt="Female2" />
                            </a>
                            <div class="footer">
                                <a href='/member/4/female-2-asian-male-tp'>Female2</a>
                                <span> - <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i> Victoria, Docklands<br /></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="tile">
                            <div class="badges">
                                <span class="best-seller">Online</span>
                            </div>
                            <a href='/member/5/hello%2c-is-it-me-your-looking-for'>
                                <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/q_100,c_fill,h_255,w_255,g_face/j6xnf3lu2gffviv1qkw3" alt="Tester123" />
                            </a>
                            <div class="footer">
                                <a href='/member/5/hello%2c-is-it-me-your-looking-for'>Tester123</a>
                                <span> - <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i> Victoria, Melbourne<br /></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="tile">
                            <div class="badges">
                            </div>
                            <a href='/member/2/i-am-a-female-from-melbourne'>
                                <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/q_100,c_fill,h_255,w_255,g_face/hyssjfqilmyntk9gvi4r" alt="Female1" />
                            </a>
                            <div class="footer">
                                <a href='/member/2/i-am-a-female-from-melbourne'>Female1</a>
                                <span> - <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i> Victoria, Melbourne<br /></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                        <div class="tile">
                            <div class="badges">
                            </div>
                            <a href='/member/3/male-2-lookin-for-male-training-partner'>
                                <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/c_fill,h_255,w_255,g_face/no-photo_pwpgkz" alt="Male2" />
                            </a>
                            <div class="footer">
                                <a href='/member/3/male-2-lookin-for-male-training-partner'>Male2</a>
                                <span> - <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i> Victoria, Southbank<br /></span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                    <div class="row text-center">
                        <div class="pagination-container"><ul class="pagination"><li class="active"><a>1</a></li></ul></div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</section>
```

The above is rendered by doing the following withing MVC Razor view:

```
<section class="catalog-grid">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="filters-mobile col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-4">
                <div class="shop-filters" style="display: block;">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "Members", FormMethod.Post))
                    {
                        <div class="widget">
                            <h5 class="widget-title font-alt">My Filter</h5>
                        </div>
                        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

                    }
                </div>
            </div>

 @*THIS IS WHERE THE RESULTS / PROFILES ARE RENDERED*@
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-8 ">

                <div class="row">
                    @if (ViewBag.ListOfUsers.Count > 0)
                    {
                        foreach (var t in ViewBag.ListOfUsers)
                        {
                            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                                <div class="tile">
                                    <div class="badges">
                                        @if (t.LoggedIn)
                                        {
                                            <span class="best-seller">Online</span>
                                        }
                                    </div>
                                    <a href='@Url.Action("Member", "User", new { area = "User", Id = t.UserId, slug = t.Headline})'>
                                        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(t.PhotoId))
                                        {
                                            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/q_100,c_fill,h_255,w_255,g_face/@t.PhotoId" alt="@t.Username" />
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            <img src="http://res.cloudinary.com/dncu6pqpm/image/upload/c_fill,h_255,w_255,g_face/no-photo_pwpgkz" alt="@t.Username" />
                                        }
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="footer">
                                        <a href='@Url.Action("Member", "User", new { area = "User", Id = t.UserId, slug = t.Headline})'>@t.Username</a>
                                        <span> - <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-map-marker"></i> @t.Location<br /></span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        }
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="row text-center">
                            @Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)ViewBag.ListOfUsers, page => Url.Action("Search", "Members", new { page }))
                        </div>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2 text-center">
                            <p>
                                Sorry, we couldn't find anyone within the criteria you provided.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

UPDATE

This is what it currently looks like using the above

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My initial guess, without seeing a live demo, is that only one is being shown per row because of col-sm-6. As bootstrap has a 12 column layout if there is any padding or margin applied to the objects 6+6+padding is greater than 12 and will push it to the next row. My understanding is that there should be a "div.row" for each new row. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting margin or padding, one of our devs here slapped a max-width on the tiles which caused the issue, removing this and amended the sm-size fixed the issue.